# Font awesome icon renders full screen then resizes react on page load

Tags: css, reactjs, svg, icons, font-awesome

Can not find a solution on the platform.  Have a font awesome icon using the react library and when the page loads it will render the icon full screen then resize it to the correct size.  I have sent the size property on the element `size={'md'}`.

Anyone else have experience with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See this link here [Server Size Rendering CSS](https://fontawesome.com/v5/docs/web/other-topics/server-side-rendering#css)

I've also seen others who have this issue and it had something to do with the way their stylesheets were loaded in relation to the font awesome stylesheet or script tag.

Comment: This looks like it addressed the issue per Font Awesome's doc.  It is a bit extensive to implement just for a single icon so I built a simple ternary workaround that doesn't render the icon until the window object is loaded.  This also fixed the issue for me simply.

Comment: Awesome, glad you figured out a solution @RyanCarville